# Logical Conjunction of Binary Decision Diagrams

Tags: computer-science, formal-languages

Compute a Binary Decision Diagram for $B1∧B2$. Furthermore, for an arbitrary BDD B you can use the equations $B∧F=F$, $F∧B=F$, $B∧T=B$ and $T∧B=B$.

[image: 2 Binary Decision Diagrams]

---

To construct the BDD i start from the leaves and work myself to the top. So i have:

[image]

but here is the problem:

[image]

Now i do not know how to proceed from here on. Has someone experience with Binary Decision Diagrams ? I would like to understand this problem and solve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the solution step by step :
[image: Operation on Binary Decision Diagram]